# Continuity of the closest point on a closed, but non-compact submanifold $S$ w.r.t. the point outside $S$ we measure the distance

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242002/smoothness-of-the-closest-point-on-a-submanifold), I ask the question below.

Let $S\subset M$ be a closed in $M$ but not necessary compact, embedded submanifold of a complete Riemannian manifold $M.$ Assume that for each $p \in M$, there exist a **unique** closest point on $S$, i.e a unique point $\tilde s(p) \in S$ such that $d(p,\tilde s (p))=d_S(p)=d(p,S)$.

When $S$ is compact, we can show that the map $\tilde{s}:M\to S$ is continuous, as follows:

Let $\{p_n\}\to p$ in $M.$ So now $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}\in S$ is a sequence in $S.$ Take *any* subsequence of $\{\tilde{s}({p_n}_k)\}\in S,$ which by **compactness of $S,$** has a convergent subsequence (we abuse notation and use the same indexing here) $\{\tilde{s}({p_n}_{k})\} \to s\in S.$ Now  by continuity of distance $d(.,.)$ in both arguments, $d({p_n}_{k}, \tilde{s}({p_n}_{k}))\to d(p,s).$

Next, by continuity of $d(.,S), d({p_n}_{k},S)\to d(p,S).$

By the two arguments above, $d(p,s)=d(p,S).$ By **uniqueness of the closest point and the definition of $\tilde{s}$**, $s$ must be $\tilde{s}(p).$

This shows that any subsequence of  $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}\in S$ has a convergent subsequence, converging to $\tilde{s}(p).$  This shows that the whole sequence $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}\to \tilde{s}(p), n\to \infty.$

**Question I:** Is my argument correct and complete?

**Question II:** Clearly the above argument **uses the fact that $S$ is compact**. So is $\tilde{s}$ discontinuous when $S$ is not compact? If so, what's an example?

**Question III:** Are there "nice cases" (necessary/sufficient condition on) for $S$ where the continuity is ensured?

**EDIT (following the first comment):**

Perhaps we can change the subsequence argument above to showing that if $s$ is an accumulation point of $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}\in S,$ then $s=\tilde{s}(p)$ is the only possibility. This shows that the set of accumulation point of $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}\subset S,$ if any, is unique. But how can we guarantee that there's *at least one* accumulation point?

**EDIT (following the comment by Moishe Kohan):**

We note that $d(p_n, \tilde{s}(p_n))=d(p_n,S) \le M \forall n \ge 1,$ while the last inequality is true since the sequence $\{p_n\}$ is bounded, being convergent. So $d(p_n, \tilde{s}(p_n)) \le M \forall n \ge 1.$ Now again, since the sequence $\{p_n\}$ is bounded, so is $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\} \subset S$ and $S$ being closed, $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}$ has an accumulation point. And now the preceding argument shows that the accumulation point is unique, making the sequence convergent.

Comment: It looks like compactness is only used to extract a convergent sequence from $K=\{\bar{s}(p_n)\}$. Since $S$ contains all of its accumulation points (if any), being closed, I think you might be able to construct an argument using this instead of compactness. You will have to supply the details, of course. I would start by considering whether or not $K$ has an accumulation point.

Comment: @MPW Thanks for your comment! I changed the argument slightly, but the problem might be that the set $K:=\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}\in S$ may not have an accumulation point. Or must it?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that closed bounded subsets in complete Riemannian manifolds are compact.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, I added an edit, where I showed that the sequence $\{\tilde{s}(p_n)\}$ is bounded and thus has an accumulation point in the closed set $S\subset M,$ which is complete. I think this is equivalent to your argument. Do you mind taking a quick look please? Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, I also wonder if the function $\tilde{s}:M\to S$ Lipchitz, i.e. can we say can we say $d_S(\tilde{s}(p), \tilde{s}(p'))\le Kd_M(p,p') \forall p, p'\in M?$ Someone asked the smoothness in the above link in the OP: but got a negative answer. It's clearly continuous, so I wonder if it's Lipschitz or uniformly continuous.